# Licensing for Open Source project which uses commercial libraries

Tags: license-recommendation, commercial

We are developing an application which will be Open Source (code), however there are few libraries which are either paid or commercial. We have liaised with original developers/parties and agreed to distribute Uglified and/or DLL version of these libraries with our source code with appropriate link to how to buy and include these libraries in your project if you are planning to use/extend the project.

Most of our code is JavaScript (frontend), C# (backend) & Unity (the game). Each of these components uses combination of Commercial & Copyleft libraries.

So can someone educate us on which licensing template we should be using for the project.

Comment: What precise proprietary libraries are you exactly using, and what are their licensing?

Comment: Some libraries that we are planning to use are Sencha Ext JS & Rappid - JointJS. Which are commercially licensed. And we will be including compiled/obfuscated version of their source.

Comment: That should go into the question. And you might ask your proprietary libraries providers if you can do what you intend to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I license an open source application that uses closed source libraries?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/how-do-i-license-an-open-source-application-that-uses-closed-source-libraries)

Answer (score 2):

An open-source project can use proprietary libraries if the proprietary libraries in question allow for it. For the OS-part you can use a permissive license (MIT, BSD, Apache), which is allowing to combine it with works under different licenses. As you talk about libraries even some copyleft-licenses are OK, as long as linking isn't counted as derivate work (so LGPL is ok, GPL or AGPL aren't).

What confuses me a bit is you talking about C# and Unity using commercial and copyleft-licenses. Are these the libraries you use under commercial license? Or are you using them with copyleft and different libraries in proprietary license? If the second, then the copyleft-license influences your project and might prohibit the combination with proprietary licensed stuff (depending on the license in question).

Comment: For C# & Unity bits, its combination of commercial & opensource licenses.